# Error: Nuxt instance is unavailable! In Vitest with Nuxt environment

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, vitest

I'm busy implementing unit tests for our Nuxt application. Testing components that don't use any Nuxt modules run fine without any issues but testing a component with an installed Nuxt module throws `Error: Nuxt instance is unavailable!`

#### The test file

`Logo.nuxt.test.ts`

```js
import { mountSuspended } from 'nuxt-vitest/utils'

import Logo from '~/components/product/Logo.vue'

const createWrapper = () => mountSuspended(Logo, {
  props: {
    alt: 'test',
    src: 'test',
    sizes: 'test',
    width: 20,
    height: 20,
    preset: 'card-list-logo',
  },
  global: {
    stubs: ['nuxt-img'],
  },
})

describe('Product list logo', () => {
  test('test', async () => {
    const wrapper = await createWrapper()
    console.log(wrapper.html())
  })
})
```

#### The component

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
// https://image.nuxt.com/usage/nuxt-img

defineProps<{
  alt: string
  src: string
  sizes: string
  width: number
  height: number
  preset: 'card-list-logo' | 'product-detail-logo'
}>()
</script>

<template>
  <figure>
    <NuxtImg
      class="product-logo"
      :src="src"
      :alt="alt"
      :placeholder="[width, height]"
      :width="width"
      :height="height"
      :sizes="sizes"
      :preset="preset"
      loading="lazy"
    />
  </figure>
</template>
```

#### The Error

```
Error: Nuxt instance is unavailable!
 ❯ useNuxt ../node_modules/@nuxt/kit/dist/index.mjs:32:11
 ❯ installNuxtModule ../node_modules/nuxt/dist/chunks/features.mjs:41:16
 ❯ ../node_modules/nuxt/dist/index.mjs:1290:77
```

When I comment out `NuxtImg` it works fine. This is the `@nuxt/image` module.

`NuxtLink` tests without issues so I expect the issue to be inside of `NuxtImg`

Hoping someone can shine some light on this.

I also tried stubbing it out but that didn't work